# Parsing XML response from RESTful service in java

Tags: java, xml, rest

Please bear with me for this novice question.

I am calling a RESTful web service APIs that returns XML response. Apart from normal XML parsing schemes like DOM based parsing, SAX based parsing, is there a way to transform this XML response directly into some object? What more details/specification from service side would be required to do such transformation?

Comment: do you have a schema for the xml?

Comment: I don't think so. To be more precise about service, It's LinkedIn web service API's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i can't give a summary of all the options available, but i recently used [jaxb](http://jaxb.java.net/) to do the opposite (java to xml) and it was simple and easy to use.  since jaxb also supports xml to java, as described [here](http://jaxb.java.net/2.2.5/docs/ch03.html#unmarshalling), i would suggest giving that a look.  it's based on annotations and java beans (or pojos) - you just indicate which attributes correspond to the elements with attributions, and it does the rest.

if you have a schema, it will generate java classes for you.  alternatively, [here's an example of working without a schema](http://duckranger.com/2011/06/jaxb-without-a-schema/).

ps according to comments in the final link, you don't even need to annotate if the names match the xml!

Comment: +1 JAXB is very easy to use. There is an unofficial schema for the LinkedIn API here: http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/source/browse/trunk/linkedin-j/core/src/main/resources/com/google/code/linkedinapi/schema/linkedin-api-schema.xsd.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for link to example of working without a schema. It's very helpful.

Comment: no problem.  but given the size of the schema @kevingallagher linked to, you might be best using that.  could save a lot of work...

Comment: @Kevin LinkedIn has two/three different API's so ideally there would be different schema for each API. am I right?

Comment: just looking at the two, it seems like the schema contains all the different replies to the REST service in one schema.  for example, one of the groups api calls http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api returns a `group-membership` element which is present in kevin's schema here http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/source/browse/trunk/linkedin-j/core/src/main/resources/com/google/code/linkedinapi/schema/linkedin-api-schema.xsd#1337 (there's also a javascript api but it looks like it returns json).  good luck.

Comment: LinkedIn-J project is itself a good reference. I would go through it once to understand things in detail. thnx